# Counting pages within certain chapters or sections of a book class document

Tags: counters, zref, refcount

**Problem:** For a document I need to submit to my university, the word count is unimportant but the page count is required to be equal to or less than a certain value (32 in this case). In the executive summary part of my document, I am including a footnote which includes the total page counts and details over what is included (i.e. executive summary and chapters only, TOC and appendices do not count). I am unsure how to count the page numbers as the pages changed from roman numerals in `frontmatter` to numbering in the `mainmatter` and a search here could not find a similar question (although if this is a duplicate I am happy to delete).

**What I would like:** A method to count the total pages of the executive summary and the `mainmatter` chapters which excludes parts I do not wish to be counted (front page, TOC, appendices and other `backmatter`) if this is possible. I have used TeXCount before to count words and know it can be turned on or off based on `%TC:ignore` and a similar method or a more basic solution would be ideal. In the MWE, the `#` would ideally be automatically updated to include the page count of the desired sections.

**What I have tried:** Unfortunately, I have attempted little to put the page count automatically as I am not very experienced with the book class and likewise with counters which I am assuming is required here. My back-up option is to just put the value in manually although I wouldn't mind an automatic version I could then use in other documents.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}     % For dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage} Title \end{titlepage}

% ------------------------ Included in page count
\chapter{Executive Summary}
 Text \footnote{The total page numbers including the executive summary and chapters is \# pages}. \lipsum[1-10].
% ------------------------ ^^ Included in page count

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\mainmatter

% ------------------------ Included in page count
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Third}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Fourth}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Fifth}
\lipsum[1-10]
% ------------------------ ^^ Included in page count

\appendix
\chapter{Text}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I hope this is enough detail, if this is a duplicate then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE produces 23 pages: title page (1) Executive Summary (3), ToC (1), chapters (15)  and Appendix (5).

The title page and appendix should be excluded from the page count, giving a net count of 19 pages.

Using the `pageslts` package it is possible to get a reference of the last page regardless of the numbering style. For example `\lastpageref{LastPages}` will output the physical page number of the last page (23, but numbered 18).

The label `lastpagetocount` was added to mark the last page to count.

To convert the `LastPages` and the other page references to  numbers, it was  used the `\getpagerefnumber` command provided by the `refcount` package.

For convenience, the `netpages` counter contains the result of the net number of pages to count, and the `\NetPages` command will insert that number into the footnote.

The net number of pages to count is given by

```
\getpagerefnumber{LastPages} -\getpagerefnumber{LastPage} +\getpagerefnumber{lastpagetocount} -1
```

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}     % For dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{refcount}  % convert pages references to numbers \getpagerefnumber <<<<<<
\usepackage{pageslts} % reference to the last physical pages <<<<<<
\newcounter{netpages} % store net number of pages to count <<<<<<
\newcommand{\NetPages}{% % added <<<<<<
\setcounter{netpages}{\the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPages} -\getpagerefnumber{LastPage} +\getpagerefnumber{lastpagetocount} -1\relax}
\thenetpages}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \begin{titlepage} Title     
 \end{titlepage} 
% ------------------------ Included in page count
\chapter{Executive Summary} 

Text \footnote{The total page numbers including the executive summary and chapters is \NetPages~pages}. \lipsum[1-10].
% ------------------------ ^^ Included in page count

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\mainmatter

% ------------------------ Included in page count
\chapter{First}     
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Third}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Fourth}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Fifth}
\lipsum[1-10]
\label{lastpagetocount} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
% ------------------------ ^^ Included in page count%       
\appendix
\chapter{Text}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

There was only supposed to be one page before the executive summary. Hence the -1 in the formula. If you have more pages present, change that number accordingly.

**UPDATE** This solution uses only the package `zref`. It will count the pages between `\zlabel{firstpagetocount}` and `\zlabel{lastpagetocount}`, so it doesn't matter how many pages there are before or after that marks.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[abspage,user,lastpage]{zref} % added <<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{lipsum}     % For dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{netpages} % store net number of pages to count <<<<<<   
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\calculatepages}{%  
\setcounter{netpages}{\numexpr\zref@extract{lastpagetocount}{abspage} -\zref@extract{firstpagetocount}{abspage}+1\relax}    
\thenetpages\       
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \begin{titlepage} Title     
 \end{titlepage} 
% ------------------------ Included in page count
\chapter{Executive Summary} 
\zlabel{firstpagetocount}   % mark first page to count  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
Text \footnote{The total page numbers including the executive summary and chapters is \calculatepages pages}. \lipsum[1-10].
% ------------------------ ^^ Included in page count

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\mainmatter

% ------------------------ Included in page count
\chapter{First} 
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Third}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Fourth}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Fifth}
\lipsum[1-10]
\zlabel{lastpagetocount} %  % mark last page to count   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
% ------------------------ ^^ Included in page count%       
\appendix
\chapter{Text}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @James_T Thank you for your feedback!.  There was only supposed to be one page before the executive summary. Hence the -1 in the formula. If you have more pages present, like a ToC, change that number accordingly. I will think about it.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment just before you made yours as your edit made sense! To anyone who revisits this in the future, my comment was along the lines of "How can I exclude the TOC from the page count" to which @Simon Dispa mentioned that the -1 in the `\setcounter{netpages}{...}` command was the TOC page number and to change this for different TOC page number values. Thanks for your answer :)